# Norm of an operator in separable Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space, $\mathcal{H}_0$ be a dense subset of $\mathcal{H}$, and $T:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ be a bounded linear operator which is not self-adjoint. We know that
$$   
\lim_{n\to\infty} \langle f,T^n g\rangle = 0, \qquad \forall f\in\mathcal{H}_0,\ \forall g\in\mathcal{H}. 
$$
What can we say about $\|T\|$? Can we say $\|T\| \le 1$ or even $\|T\|<1$?

If no, under what conditions on $T$ can we say $\|T\|<1$?

What I have done so far: If $f_n:=(T^*)^nf$, then $f_n\to 0$ in weak topology. So $\sup_n\|f_n\| =\sup_n\|(T^*)^nf\|<\infty$. If I could apply uniformly bounded theorem, I could show $\|(T^*)^n\|=\|T^n\|\le B<\infty$, and then I had $r(T) =\lim_n \|T^n\|^{\frac{1}{n}} \le 1$ but $r(T)\le \|T\|$.

EDIT: Similar answers and questions for other forms of the norm (Frobenius, trace, etc), and even when $T$ is self-adjoint,  are of high interest.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T$ be any nil-potent non-zero operator. Then your hypothisis satisfied by $T$ as well as any mutiple of $T$. [ $T^{n}=0$ implies $T^{m}=0$ for all $m \geq n$]. Hence, there is no hope for bounding the norm of $T$.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. What if $T$ is a compact operator?

Comment: There are nil-potent compact operators. @MohammadKhosravi

Comment: I see. How about other forms of the norm? (I have edited the questions)